# Add a class to a row on a dynatable table, but after a search they are gone

Tags: jquery, dynatable

I want to add a class("fila_art") to every row in a dynatable table so when i click on them another one is added("marcar").
I tried this:

```
$('#tableId').dynatable({
    table: {
        defaultColumnIdStyle: 'camelCase'
    }
}).bind('dynatable:afterProcess', processingComplete());

function processingComplete (){
        $("#tableId").children("tbody").children().addClass("fila_art");
}

$( ".fila_art" ).live("click", function() {
    $(".fila_articulo").removeClass("marcar");
    $(this).addClass("marcar");
});
```

But when i make a search on the table the code stop working and i can't add the class("marcar") anymore. I checked the code after the search and the class "fila_art" was not added anymore.
Any ideas? 
Sorry about the spelling.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been deprecated since v1.7 and totally removed on v1.9.

Comment: Can you provide us a jsFiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: Already try with on() and is the same. here is the jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/chatoxz/uzc3vcfh/

Comment: `bind('dynatable:afterProcess', processingComplete())` is wrong. Correct is `processingComplete` without the parens because you are passing the function as a callback -- you don't want to call it on the spot!

Comment: It doesn't work wihtout the parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uzc3vcfh/4/)

```
var processingComplete = function(){
    $("#tableId").children("tbody").children().addClass("fila_art");
};

$('#tableId').dynatable({
    table: {
        defaultColumnIdStyle: 'camelCase'
    }
}).bind('dynatable:afterProcess', processingComplete);

processingComplete();

$('body').on('click', '.fila_art' ,function(){
    $(".fila_art").removeClass("marcar");
    $(this).addClass("marcar");
});
```

From jQuery Documentation: [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

> If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event

Placing the selector `.file_art` as a parameter designates it as a delegated event.